# AVCaptureSession stopRunning hangs the main thread on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avfoundation, avcapturesession

This is specific to iOS 8. I noticed that there was a severe delay after calling AVCaptureSession stopRunning and I'm very confused as to why this is happening.

The relevant code:

```
static dispatch_queue_t _captureQueue;

@implementation myClass {
  AVCaptureSession *_session;
}

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // standard AVCaptureSession setup (I can put actual code in if need be)
    static dispatch_once_t queueOnce;
    dispatch_once(&queueOnce, ^{
        _captureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myclass.captureQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    });
  }
}

- (void)start {
  if (!_session) return;

  dispatch_async(_captureQueue, ^{
    [self->_session startRunning];
  });
}

- (void)stop {
  if (!_session) return;

  // stopMethod#1
  //[_session stopRunning];

  // stopMethod#2
  //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  //  [self->_session stopRunning];
  //});

  // stopMethod#3
  dispatch_async(_captureQueue, ^{
    [self->_session stopRunning];
  });
}
```

stopMethod#3 is the way that I've always stopped AVCaptureSessions in the past and it is the method that is currently causing the delay I'm seeing. I was wondering if there was a long running method on the _captureQueue and that was causing the delay when stopRunning was sent to it, but upon using stopMethod#2 I saw the exact same delay. I finally tried stopping the session on the main thread and I had no delay at all. Remember all this is on iOS 8. I grabbed a device with iOS 7 on it and using all three stopMethods I received no delay (I'm just taking pictures so I'm assuming there isn't a lot to shut down).

This is very confusing to me because the documentation says

```
- (void)stopRunning
  Discussion
    This method is used to stop the flow of data from the inputs to the outputs
    connected to the AVCaptureSession instance that is the receiver. This method
    is synchronous and blocks until the receiver has completely stopped running.
```

And almost every SO post on this topic says NOT to call stopRunning on the main thread. Is this some sort of weird iOS 8 bug or am I missing something?

Comment: stopMethod#3 is the correct one.  Have you made sure that every time you call a method on the capture session (in addition to startRunning and stopRunning), it's also on the captureQueue?

Comment: Yes I have. The only other method I call is `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` on a `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` and it is dispatched onto the `_captureQueue`.